# Sync Azure Analysis Services Model using PowerShell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-analysis-services

I'm trying to sync a AAS model on a scale out AAS instance. I have one replica and the "Separate the processing server from the query pool" option enabled.

I then run this script:

```
$Server = (Get-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AASServerName).ServerFullName
$ServicePrincipalCredentialSecure = $ServicePrincipalCredential | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ServicePrincipalId,$ServicePrincipalCredentialSecure)
Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Cred -RolloutEnvironment "northeurope.asazure.windows.net" -TenantId $TenantId
Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance -Instance "$($Server):rw" -Database $Database -Verbose
```

But I receive this error:

> Sync-AzureAnalysisServicesInstance : {"CorrelationId":"e54ac23d-4be3-478c-a8a4-af2981fa3775","OperationId":null,"Database":"SIMONTEST","UpdatedAt":"2019-09-02T10:07:38.0522507+01:00","StartedAt":"20 
>   19-09-02T10:07:38.0522507+01:00","SyncState":-1,"Details":"Failed to send sync request to specified server. ServerName: xxxx:rw, RootActivityId:
>   4a5b2459-5d28-4263-a49c-6d483ac8c32c, Date (UTC): 9/2/2019 9:07:37 AM, Details: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).."}

I notice that the commands are Azure not AzureRM - which is odd but is what the documentation shows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.analysisservices/sync-azureanalysisservicesinstance?view=azurermps-5.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Looks we miss to add the service principal to the server administrator role, I add it and it works.

You could follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-addservprinc-admins) to add the service principal in the SSMS.

Note: If you could not find the service principal by name, you can also write `app:<application id>@<tenant id>` in the `Manual Entry` -> `Add` -> `OK`.

Comment: Thanks Joy. I was going to raise a support ticket myself but I do not have permission on the subscription :(

Comment: @simon_dmorias Hi, seems we need to add the service principal to the server administrator role, check my update.

Comment: many thanks you are completely right. Feeling stupid right now.